How to test a script that pushes gems?
I have this script:
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

if ARGV.any?
  puts "USAGE: release"
  exit
end

def system!(command)
  puts command
  system(command, exception: true)
end

File.delete(*Dir["*.gem"])
system!("gem build")
system!("gem push *.gem")
File.delete(*Dir["*.gem"])

That I simply call release (it's part of the dorian-release gem).
I'm trying to test it, but not sure how to best do it, chatgpt suggests stubs but that doesn't really test anything.
I would like to mock HTTP requests to rubygems, but not sure how to do it as it's subcommands.
Any idea?

If you really want to test the entire build and push workflow, you could run a local gem server for testing purposes and set it via the RUBYGEMS_HOST environment variable. This way, your script will push the gem to your local gem server.

I would argue that stubs are the right way to test a line like system!("gem push *.gem"). Because what you actually care about is that the gem pushcommand is called as expected. You should not care about what gem push does internally and how gem push pushes to Rubygems. That is private to the gem command. And we can expect that the internal implementation of the gem push command is already tested.

@spickermann I think recent versions of RSpec moved both stubs and message expectations out to rspec-mocks. Regardless, I'm not sure what it buys you if you have reasonably DAMP tests that explicitly call gem push. I mean, either it works or it doesn't, right? Unless you have some weird edge case that might or might not call the method with the #system call, or you wanted to verify the call without actually pushing, which makes it a unit test rather than an integration test. What's the value-add of stubbing the call here?

@ToddA.Jacobs. You are right, such a test would not add much benefit. And to be clear, I wouldn't write any test for the above code example. Because it is too trivial, and IHMO doesn't require any tests to add more confidence. However, in the event that testing is necessary, I would opt to stub it, as it is still superior to writing tests that test the internal implementation details of a third-party tool.

@ToddA.Jacobs I didn't get your point about rspec being separated into different gems. Would you mind elaborating? I think I am missing something.

@spickermann Mocks, stubs, and doubles are now part of rspec-mocks rather than included in rspec-core or rspec-expectations, so they work a little differently than they used to. Besides saying that such mocks don't test anything real, I was also trying to say that including rspec-mocks for the sole purpose of creating an RSpec::Mocks::Double that must then allow(dbl).to receive just so you can then expect(dbl).to receive creates additional complexity and an extra set of dependencies without creating useful isolation or validation for the OP's specific use case.

Don't Test Dependency Internals in Application Specs

I would like to mock HTTP requests to rubygems, but not sure how to do it as it's subcommands.

No, no, no! While it can be valid to perform some kind of integration testing to ensure that your application has accomplished some intended system change, unit, functional, and integration tests should not be testing the internals of other libraries. You need to rethink your goal here.
As a clearer example, unless you're working on interpreter internals you should never be testing how Kernel#puts works, although you may occasionally find a use case for validating that $stdout or $stderr are pointing where you expect, or even that the output sent to a stream contains the correct interpolated output you expected. Testing whether Kernel#puts itself works should never be a focus for your tests.
In the same vein, making sure that gem push pushes your gem to RubyGems or a test server doesn't require anything complex. Unless you're deep into debugging, all you really need to know is whether the gem got published or not. If you don't trust gem push to return the correct exit status or raise an exception—you probably should, as this is a widely used piece of the Ruby ecosystem, and seems like it's more of a proxy test for verifying your firewall rules or something similar—then you should check the server to see if the new gem version was published.
You can do this in many different ways, depending on the level of complexity you actually need. I'd keep it as simple as possible, because otherwise you're down the rabbit hole of testing test dependencies, which is masochistic and generally unnecessary. In order of simple to more complex:

Test that your globbing of local gems to publish is correct.

Ensure your glob returns only valid values, and handles invalid values correctly.
Ensure the application does the right thing when the file list is empty, nil, or contains some other invalid value.


Rely on the exit status or exceptions from RubyGems.

Check the output of gem list -r #{gem_name} against your expectations.

Use the OpenURI module to grab the contents of the web page from a RubyGems server and grep for your expected version number.

Parse the RubyGems web page with Nokogiri and use Gem::Version to compare semantic versions.

Use gem methods from the RubyGems Web Server API to query it for details on your published gems.


Tracing the internals of the RubyGems HTTP(S) calls is something you shouldn't normally be doing unless you're a RubyGems developer. For anyone else, if you're going deeper than running a testing proxy to see why your HTTP(S) calls are failing at the network or protocol levels you're creating unnecessary overhead. Test applications at the application layer, and if you rely on common external libraries trust their tests to validate that they work as intended!

I mean I would be fine mocking system calls, e.g. that gem push is called

@Dorian But that's not what your code does. You aren't calling Gem#push, you're calling a method that shells out and invokes gem push.  Given the example code, why would you even need to validate that your custom #system! method is invoked? It's just a wrapper around Kernel#system, which should be relied on to return a valid exit code or raise an exception. I stand by my point that you're testing the wrong thing here; you don't have your code wrapped in a class, so you'd have to stub and set expectations on TOPLEVEL. This should be an integration test, not a mock.
